# WSO2 ESB Clustered databases and Data Services

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I could setup a cluster of wso2 ESB, following the dedicated doc, with a manager and two workers.

I am not sure about two points:

Does each worker node need it's own REGISTRY_LOCAL database ?
With both workers using the same db it works, but I'm not sure it is the way to do and the doc isn't clear about that.

Adding Data Services as a feature ?
Almost no docs about that, but not being able to fetch more than one row is a big limitation for me, so is it possible to add this feature in a clustered environment or is it better to separate the Data Services Servers from the ESB ones ?

If someone has experience in that kind of stuff I will really appreciate a feedback.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same registry database for all the members in the cluster so that they can communicate with each other using that. You may refer my blog [1] for further information. Personally I have never used local registry DBs for each member in the cluster setup.

You cannot fetch multiple records when you install the DSS feature into the ESB. Also installing the feature will incur some performance overheads in the ESB. Therefore I thoroughly recommend you to use a separate DSS instance to get your work done. It also separates the concerns clearly which sounds good.

[1] http://ravindraranwala.blogspot.com/2015/09/wso2-esb-worker-manager-cluster-without.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will have a look on your blog.